# I want my xslt to transform my xml to a html maintaining it's xml structure?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is my xml upon which i want the transformation.

```
<topic>
  <body>
    <section>
       <p>---</p>
       <p>-----</p>
       <ul>
          <li>---</li>
          <li>----</li>
       </ul>
       <p>---</p>
    </section>
 <metaData>
  |
  |
  |
</metaData>
  </body>
</topic>
```

I want the xslt which will output me this html like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>abcd...</p>
            <p>abcdefg.......</p>
            <ul>
                <li/>
                <li/>
                <li/>
            </ul>
            <p>..</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can same structure be maintained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserving the structure but renaming some elements is easy if you start your code with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then add templates for the elements you want to transform e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="topic">
  <html>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen .Sorry for replying so late .I tried this thing it gave me the result with the structure maintained properly but with some garbage value like am getting the xml 3 times as output and with the metaData node inside it.
Note:-This xsl file is getting called from another file with the help of <xsl:call-template>.
Thanks. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want the `metaData` elements to produce any output then add `<xsl:template match="metaData"/>`. The whole approach is not meant to be used with `call-template`, it is centered around push style processing using template matching and `apply-templates` which normally suffices. I can't tell why you think you need `call-template`, we would need to see your code to tell more. So edit your question or post a new one, providing the details.